# Editor Expanding Upwards in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an editor in a grid at the bottom of a page with auto expands.

However, as it is at the bottom of the page, it expands beyond the bottom of the page.

Is there any way to make it expand upwards like WhatsApp does?

The editor is pretty standard.

`<Editor AutoSize=”TextChanged” IsVisible="true" x:Name="Editor"  Placeholder="Type a message..." /<`

Thank you!

Comment: can you post whole xmal page?  Grid should be able to grow dynamically.Also, try wrap the editor in stacklayout.

Comment: I've created a sample at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RJf8RkTPm5_3QWjoFpA1Ju6IcYY3vvSS/view?usp=sharing - the editor expands but doesn't decrease.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I think what you need to do is to play with the `Grid.RowSpan` property of your `Editor`.

For example, if the editor is located on the 3nd row (set at Grid.Row="2") and you want it to expand on top of the 2nd row, you can do something like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
      <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   ...
   <Editor Grid.Row="2"
           Grid.RowSpan="2"
           VerticalOptions="End"
           ... />
</Grid>
```

The `Grid.RowSpan` allows you to expand the element to the row below.
You can see more here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.grid.rowspanproperty?view=xamarin-forms

I hope it helped